# CSS overflow not working with transform

Tags: html, css

I have image that is zoomed on hover, but I want it to stay within the original height and width. I have tried setting overflow:none, but it is still larger than the original size after the transform.

```html
<style type="text/css">
img.image {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease; /* Firefox */
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease; /* IE 9 */
    -o-transition: all 1s ease; /* Opera */
    transition: all 1s ease;
    height:278;
    width:185;
    overflow:hidden;
}

img.image:hover {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.1); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.1); /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.1); /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.1); /* Opera */
    transform:scale(1.1);
    overflow:hidden;
    height:278;
    width:185;
}

</style>

<img class="image" src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/l2u1MDnR89ptsKZDxIF4LFTiBWP.jpg">
```

Comment: FYI, IE9 doesn't support -ms-transition, only -ms-transform. The -ms-transition property is not used anywhere. Also your heights and widths are missing units.

Comment: I keep wondering where "-ms-" came from. It's mostly an invention of web tutorial writers; IE10 started with the standard property, and didn't bother with an experimental version of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daxtbppk/).

If you wrap the image in a div with the `overflow:hidden` property, then scale the image within that div, it achieves the result you are looking for.

The way you were doing it, the `overflow:hidden` property was being applied to the image itself. When you scale the image larger, you're just making the image bigger. There is no overflow to hide. Constraining the image within a fixed size div and then scaling the image inside hides the div's overflow (the edges of the image)

Comment: That mean the overflow should be in the parent container. right

Answer (score 1):

use a div container for it and put image inside and and overflow:hidden;

demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/locateganesh/5mbgcrjm/)

```
<div class="img-xon">
<img class="image" src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/l2u1MDnR89ptsKZDxIF4LFTiBWP.jpg" />
</div>

.img-xon{
height:278;
width:185;
overflow:hidden;
}
img.image {
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
-moz-transition: all 1s ease; /* Firefox */
-ms-transition: all 1s ease; /* IE 9 */
-o-transition: all 1s ease; /* Opera */
transition: all 1s ease;
height:278;
width:185;
}

img.image:hover {
overflow:hidden;
height:278;
width:185;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look this result. [link](http://jsbin.com/dihanesupu/1/)

You need use block for overflow:hidden